# How do you scale SKSpirteNode without anti aliasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, textures, sprite-kit

I am trying to scale an SKSpriteNode object without smoothing/anti-aliasing (I'm using pixel-art so it looks better pixelated).

Is there a property I need to set to do this? This is the code I am using to render the sprite:

```
SKTextureAtlas *atlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"objects"];
SKTexture *f1 = [atlas textureNamed:@"hero_1.png"];

SKSpriteNode *hero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:f1];
[self addChild: hero];

hero.scale = 6.0f;
```

The image is scaled correctly but blurry/smoothed out. This is hero_1.png [image].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try,

```
SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"Fak4o"];
texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
SKSpriteNode *newHero = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:texture];
newHero.position = CGPointMake(200, 200);
[newHero setScale:50];
[self addChild:newHero];
```

> **SKTextureFilteringNearest**
>
> Each pixel is drawn using the nearest point in the texture. This mode
>   is faster, but the results are often pixelated.

Swift:

```
sprite.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest
```

Comment: its not a property of skspritenode.

Comment: can you add you sprite to question so I can try a few things

Comment: i added to the question

Comment: that works! thanks - Is there a way to do this without extracting a snapshot using SKView's textureFromNode:?

Comment: try new way in answer.

Comment: that works - but it doesn't work with SKTextureAtlas

Comment: This is beautiful. +1

Comment: To do this in Swift:  sprite.texture!.filteringMode = .Nearest

Comment: @DogCoffee Is there a way to set the filteringMode for all SKTextures? So that I don't have to set it for each separately.

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, if you create a `SKSpriteNode` instead of `SKTexture`, you can set the `SKTextureFilteringNearest` like in the following example:

```
SKSpriteNode *asteroid = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"o1"];
asteroid.size = CGSizeMake(36, 24);
asteroid.position = CGPointMake(startX, startY);
asteroid.name = @"obstacle";
// >>>
asteroid.texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
// <<<
[self addChild:asteroid];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
hero.xscale = 6.0f;
hero.yscale = 6.0f;
```