# How can I get pixelated textures in SpriteKit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

How can I set `SKTextureFilteringNearest` as default filtering mode for all my SKTextures? If I don't set the filtering to nearest it appears that all my sprite's edges are blurry.

Comment: Why not just load the texture and set texture.filterindMode afterwards? You can make a SKTexture category method that applies the filtering mode if this is really too much trouble to ask for. Replacing the original method is a brutal, over-the-top solution.

Comment: not sure if this will help you, but this allows you to scale and keep the pixelated effect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193005/how-do-you-scale-skspirtenode-without-anti-aliasing/19193034#19193034

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Why is this brutal and over the top? I'd like to know why you'd oppose to a solution such as this if it were in your own project? It's a simple and elegant solution if you ask me. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) would apply here.

Comment: @Smick That's exactly what this solution does except I don't have to do it for every texture.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it changes the behavior of a built-in Sprite Kit function. Okay if this works for you, fine. But you may need to create a texture without the filteringMode changed, so you're only shifting the problem. A better solution would simply be to have separate initializer for this, like "textureWithImageNamed:filteringMode:" where you can specify the mode directly. Or even "textureNearestFilteredWithImageNamed:" - it makes the intent clearer and leaves the original untouched and still available.

Comment: It's fine to post solutions that you've discovered or invented, but you still need to stick to SO's question/answer format. You should write an actual question, such as "How can I load a pixelated texture?" You can then answer your own question and provide the solution you've found there.

Comment: Also, if you check the documentation you'll find that subclassing `SKTexture` isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the answer for the question and added it as answer instead. Removed the subclassing as well. Thanks for heads up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteKit sets the default filteringMode for all textures using `SKTextureFilteringLinear` which results in fuzzy images (especially when scaling). To get around this issue you can create a category for `SKTexture` and `SKTextureAtlas` and call the proper methods. Or you could use method swizzling for `textureWithImageNamed:`

**SKTexture+DefaultSwizzle.h**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface SKTexture (DefaultSwizzle)
@end
```

**SKTexture+DefaultSwizzle.m**

```
#import "SKTexture+DefaultSwizzle.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h> // Include objc runtime for method swizzling methods

@implementation SKTexture (DefaultSwizzle)

+ (SKTexture *)swizzled_textureWithImageNamed:(NSString*)filename
{
    // This is the original. At this point the methods have already been switched
    // which means that `swizzled_texture*` is the original.
    SKTexture *texture = [SKTexture swizzled_textureWithImageNamed:filename];

    // Set 'nearest' as default mode
    texture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

    return texture;
}

+ (void)load
{
    Method original, swizzled;

    original = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(textureWithImageNamed:));
    swizzled = class_getClassMethod(self, @selector(swizzled_textureWithImageNamed:));
    // Swizzle methods
    method_exchangeImplementations(original, swizzled);
}

@end
```

Comment: Why the down vote? Does this method not work?

Answer (score 0):

I propose a different solution that works without swizzling and leaves the original method intact:

```
@interface SKTexture (FilteringModeCategory)
+(SKTexture*) textureWithImageNamed:(NSString*)file
                      filteringMode:(SKTextureFilteringMode)mode;
+(SKTexture*) textureNearestFilteredWithImageNamed:(NSString*)file;
@end
```

The implementation:

```
@implementation SKTexture (FilteringModeCategory)

+(SKTexture*) textureWithImageNamed:(NSString*)file 
                      filteringMode:(SKTextureFilteringMode)mode
{
    SKTexture* tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:file];
    tex.filteringMode = mode;
    return tex;
}

+(SKTexture*) textureNearestFilteredWithImageNamed:(NSString*)file
{
    SKTexture* tex = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:file];
    tex.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
    return tex;
}

@end
```

Feel free to rename the second method. How about: crispyTextureWithImageNamed? :)

PS: `SKTextureAtlas` may need corresponding `textureNamed:filteringMode:` and `textureNearestFilteredNamed:` category methods too.

Comment: The "problem" with your solution is that it can't be used (as I said in de the description) the way I want it, that you'd also have to overwrite `SKTextureAtlas` because it uses `textureWithImageNamed`. If you'd like to get your (my) wanted behaviour this solution is the 'only' correct one (imho). But if you oppose to the solution I guess that's fine. I just thought I'd share it.

In my project, I wouldn't ever want to use linear filtering (@your comment on my opposed solution)

Comment: Where does SKTextureAtlas use textureWithImageNamed, when loading the atlas via atlasNamed:? Adding a textureNearestFilteredNamed: to SKTextureAtlas shouldn't be the issue. Again, it is better to use a different API if the results are different, rather than trying to shoehorn it onto the existing API and changing its default behavior. It's ok if you're ok with that, but as a general solution for other people I find such changes problematic, because often such code is applied without fully understanding it. I'm not just thinking about you. ;)

Comment: No, when loading a texture via an atlas with `textureNamed`. I understand you're not just thinking about me (;-)) but have a look at the title of this 'question'; It's called "Change Sprite Kit default texture mode", not "How to get pixelated texture's in Sprite Kit". Now I understand where your coming from and that changing default behaviour might be "wrong" in some (if not most) cases, but like I said I wanted to change the default behaviour, this is what I came up with and there's no other way to do so (I think!)